# Setting format and value in input type="date"

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, mobile-safari

Is there any way to set the format of `<input type="date" />` ? if no then how can i set date in this field using JavaScript in the default format of `type="date"`. how can i get what will be the format of this field?

**EDIT :**
Actually i want to show native date-picker of mobile device that's why i picked this type of input. if is there any alternate for that field that also will b good to have.

Sorry if i said anything stupid. Please guide me

Comment: You should clarify what you wish to set as the value of the control. The format for it, in the `value` attribute, is fixed. Is your question about converting some date value from some format (which?) to that format?

Comment: as wachk said input type date is 'YYYY-MM-DD', initially i wanted to change that format to 'DD-MM-YYYY'. and if we can open the default calendar(date-picker) of mobile device with JS then i can skip using input type date

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The format is `YYYY-MM-DD`. You cannot change it.

`$('#myinput').val('2013-12-31');` sets value

Comment: on all browsers will it be YYYY-MM-DD ? in case of mobile safari and android ?

Comment: the internal value may be read and written as YYYY-MM-DD but that isn't necessarily how it will be presented -- the browser will present the value how it decides to, which in the case of mobile devices will look at the user's locale settings and use that format

Comment: my format is set to dd-mm-yyyy ?  whats up with this?

Comment: The format is set according to locale of your PC. I am in canada, for me the format of this field is mm/dd/yyyy

Comment: yes, it change according the language and region of the computer

Answer (score 19):

`new Date().toISOString().split('T')[0];`

Comment: For now is the most beautiful and neat solution.

Comment: new Date().toISOString().substring(0,10) is what I use - dunno what's faster to read.

Comment: hm, this works although returns date in `YYYY-MM-DD` unlike the value of such `input` (`YYYY-MM-DD`).. is this a cross-browser locale-independent solution?

Comment: the problem with this solution is that `toISOString` always presents the timezone in zero UTC offset, thus be aware of that

Answer (score 6):

try this :)

```
function getDefaultDate(){

    var now = new Date();
    var day = ("0" + now.getDate()).slice(-2);
    var month = ("0" + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
    var today = now.getFullYear()+"-"+(month)+"-"+(day) ;

    return today;
}

$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $("#dateid").val( getDefaultDate()); 
});
```

Answer (score 3):

Canadian locale happens to follow the same format, too:

```
new Date().toLocaleDateString('en-CA')
```

Answer (score 2):

Easier than the above is

```
var today = new Date().toISOString().substring(0,10); # "2013-12-31"
```

Answer (score 1):

It's ugly, but it works. :/

```
var today = new Date().toLocaleString('en-GB').split(' ')[0].split('/').reverse().join('-');
```

Comment: That would give you date strings like "2015,-05-01". To remove the unnecessary comma, try this

new Date().toLocaleString('en-GB').split(' ')[0].split('/').reverse().join('-').replace(',','');

Answer (score 0):

Please check this https://stackoverflow.com/a/9519493/1074944 and try this way also `$('input[type="date"]').datepicker().prop('type','text');` check the [demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hWpsR/)

Answer (score 0):

I think this can help

```
function myFormatDateFunction(date, format) {
     ...
}

jQuery('input[type="date"]')                                             
    .each(function(){                                                              
        Object.defineProperty(this,'value',{                                         
          get: function() {                                   
            return myFormatDateFunction(this.valueAsDate, 'dd.mm.yyyy');      
          },                                                                         
          configurable: true,                                                        
          enumerable : true                                                          
        });                                                                          
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function getDefaultDate(curDate){
var dt = new Date(curDate);`enter code here`
var date = dt.getDate();
var month = dt.getMonth();
var year = dt.getFullYear();
if (month.toString().length == 1) {
    month = "0" + month
}
if (date.toString().length == 1) {
    date = "0" + date
}
return year.toString() + "-" + month.toString() + "-" + date.toString();
}
```

In **function** pass your date string.

Answer (score 0):

@cOnstructOr provided a great idea, but it left a comma in place

```
var today = new Date().toLocaleString('en-GB').split(' ')[0].slice(0,-1).split('/').reverse().join('-');
```

fixes that

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is fetch the value from the input and assign it to a new Date instance.

```
let date = document.getElementById('dateInput');

let formattedDate = new Date(date.value);

console.log(formattedDate);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple answer,

Since this is a string, we can use Javascript String slice method to rearrange the characters

```
<input type="date" id="idate" name="tno"><br>
<button onclick="run()">Run</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
function run() {
var d = document.getElementById("idate").value;

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = d.slice(8, 10) + "/" + d.slice(5, 7) + "/" + d.slice(0, 4);
}
</script>
```

Source

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_string.asp