# java script input date html format

Tags: javascript, html, date, datepicker

By default input date picker shows MM-DD-YYYY in html.

```
<input type="date" id="gdatum" />
```

Is there a way to change the mask to DD-MM-YYYY?

Answer (score 0):

```
The format is YYYY-MM-DD. You cannot change it.

$('#myinput').val('2013-12-31'); sets value
```

Sources : [Setting format and value in input type="date"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770615/setting-format-and-value-in-input-type-date)

Comment: I don't need to feed the picker, I want to see DD-MM-YYYY in HTML view. in my country first number is a day and not a month thus users will enter wrong data into the data picker