# How to change value notation of date input field in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, date

I would like to change format of date input field from dd/mm/yyy to dd.mm.yyyy
Is it possible and how and is there any chance to get that datepicker working in another browsers as well?

```
<body ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
      <input type="date" ng-model="date" value="{{date}}">
        <p>{{date}}</p>
      <input type="time" ng-model="time" value="{{time}}">    
    </div>
```

[image: How date looks now in Chrome Browser]

Comment: This is not an AngularJS problem *per se*, but a browser specific problem. Basically, the value is always in the ISO format (`YYYY-MM-DD`), while the displayed date (in the pop-up) is formatted in regard to the system/browser locale settings.

Comment: @Sami Maybe this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16770615/setting-format-and-value-in-input-type-date) helps.

Answer (score 2):

you can use custom filter for it as below

```
        <div ng-app="myApp">
           <div ng-controller="myCtrl">
             <p>{{date | divideByPoint}}</p> // displays as dd.mm.yyyy(21.12.2014)
          </div>
       </div>
```

below filter : divideByPoint

```
      var app = angular.module('myApp',[]);

 //controller
      app.controller('myCtrl',myCtrl);

         myCtrl.$inject = ["$scope"];

         function myCtrl($scope){
            $scope.date = "21/12/2014"
       }

  //filter

    app.filter('divideByPoint',function(){

     var pattern = /\//g;  
        return function(input) {
              return input.replace(pattern,'.');
           }

     })
```

https://jsfiddle.net/shushanthp/9yes55L5/

Comment: How to use filter with input type="date"?